# Como pegar conteúdo pesquisado e por no título e em search-box?

Tags: javascript

Bem, tenho uma página de pesquisa, e como faço para pegar o conteúdo pesquisado depois do "?q=" e colocar no título da página e em uma caixa de texto? Porém, se pesquisado, por exemplo, "stackoverflow beta", a url fica "stackoverflow%20beta". Tem como converter "%20" em espaço?

Comment: 'Tem como converter "%20" em espaço?' - [`decodeURIComponent(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). Quanto a pegar esses dados e jogar na página, você quer fazer isso via JavaScript? Não seria melhor fazer no lado servidor não? Se for isso mesmo que você quer, creio que é via [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.search) ou [`location.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.searchParams).

Comment: E como coloco o valor pesquisado no titulo e na search box?

Comment: Você sabe como selecionar um elemento? Como atualizar seu html ou seu valor? Está usando JavaScript puro ou alguma biblioteca como jQuery? Precisa dar suporte a browsers antigos? Por favor contextualize mais a pergunta, mostrando o que você já sabe e o que ainda falta saber.